# SQL Server query export to CSV in bash

Tags: sql-server, linux, bash

I wrote this bash script that connects to a SQL Server remote database, executes a query and saves the result (over 3000 rows) to a CSV file.
Everything seems to work, the script connects to the SQL Server but the resulting CSV file is empty.

Is there any other step or parameter I forget?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Export query to CSV

serverName="x.x.x.x,y"
database="abc"
username="user"
password="password"

tsql="select a.USERID, a.PARTYID, a.LOCKED_STATUS, a.ACTIVE_FLAG, 
        convert(varchar, a.LAST_DEPOSIT_DATE, 23) as LAST_DEPOSIT_DATE,
        b.USERID as Agent, VIP_STATUS.code as VIP_STATUS, a.KYC_STATUS 
        from external_mpt.USER_CONF a left join external_mpt.USER_CONF b 
        on b.PARTYID= a.ParentID left join admin_all.VIP_STATUS 
        on VIP_STATUS.id=a.VIP_STATUS where a.BRANDID=1 
        and a.REG_DATE <= DATEADD(HOUR,-3,GETDATE())"


# Execute the SQL query and output the result in CSV format
result=$(mssql-cli -U "$username" -P "$password" -S "$serverName" -d "$database" -Q "$tsql" -o csv)

# Output the result to a file
echo "$result" > /var/www/html/api/csv/userconf.csv
```

Comment: Can you try with -N option? it is possible that the server is using encryption

Comment: the parameter '-o csv' is sending the otuput to a file called csv. Can you check that file?

Comment: mssql-cli -U "$username" -P "$password" -S "$serverName" -d "$database" -Q "$tsql" -o csv > userconf2.csv creates the file with no content

Comment: did you try removing '-o csv'?

Comment: removing -o csv: still empty csv

Comment: @R_life_R `mssql-cli -U "$username" -P "$password" -S "$serverName" -d "$database" -Q "$tsql" -o csv > userconf2.csv` creates two files - one named `csv` will have your results, `userconf2.csv` will be empty because the command hasn't written anything to stdout.

Comment: The issue with the empty CSV file could be due to the fact that you are saving the output of the `mssql-cli` command to the result variable, and then saving the contents of that variable to the file `/var/www/html/api/csv/userconf.csv`. If the `mssql-cli` command generates a lot of output, the variable may be exceeding the maximum allowed size.